# Missing required parameters for [Route: topic.index] [URI: topic/{id}/group]

Tags: php, laravel

I want to ask how to fix this error when I delete a topic I need redirect back to topic.index but it's error

> (Missing required parameters for [Route: topic.index] [URI: topic/{id}/group].)

follow show some code  01. in `TopicController`.

I try to add `$topic follow show some code  02.` in `TopicController` it's become `404 not found` and id between `topic/{id}/group` change from id of Group to id of Topic that has been deleted

in **web.php**

```
Route::get('/topic/{id}/group', 'TopicController@index')->name('topic.index');
```

*01. in TopicController*

```
class TopicController extends Controller
{    
    public function index($id)
    {
        $group = Group::findOrFail($id);
        $topics = Topic::where('group_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        return view('topic.index', compact('group', 'topics'));
    }

    public function destroy( Topic $topic)
    {
        if ($topic != null) {
           $topic->delete();
           return redirect()->route('topic.index') ;     //*******
        }
    }
}
```

*02. in TopicController*

```
class TopicController extends Controller
{  
    public function index($id)
    {
        $group = Group::findOrFail($id);
        $topics = Topic::where('group_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        return view('topic.index', compact('group', 'topics'));
    }

    public function destroy( Topic $topic)
    {
        if ($topic != null) {
           $topic->delete();
           return redirect()->route('topic.index',$topic) ;     //*******
        }
    }
}
```

after delete a topic I need redirect back to `topic.index`

I hope to someone can help me and I hope to you understand my message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route (`topic.index`) is handled by `TopicController@index`, which requires an id of the group. So when you destroy the topic, you have to redirect it back to the group index. Therefor you need to get the `group id` before deleting the model.

You tried to redirect to a route from a recently deleted object/model, that's not possible.

Your code will look like:

```
public function destroy( Topic $topic)
{
    if ($topic) {
       $group_id = $tropic->group_id;

       $topic->delete();

       return redirect()->route('topic.index', $group_id);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And if you use the Laravel route explicit binding (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding) you don't have to check if the topic exists, this is done by Laravel. Then your code will look like this, much cleaner, right?:

```
public function destroy(Topic $topic)
{
    $group_id = $tropic->group_id;

    $topic->delete();

    return redirect()->route('topic.index', $group_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to redirect back to a topic that you have just deleted, that does not make sense, you also require an `$id` of the group, not from the topic, so try this instead:

```
public function destroy( Topic $topic)
{

    if ($topic) {
       $group = $tropic->group_id;

       $topic->delete();
       return redirect()->route('topic.index', $group);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to get `groupId` before you delete topic.
so:

```
public function destroy( Topic $topic)
{
    if ($topic != null) {
       $groupId = $topic->group_id;
       $topic->delete();
       return redirect()->route('topic.index',$groupId) ;     //*******
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As You Have Posted `topic.index` Route Contains One Parameter `id` parameter is required. That is the error in 01 Snippet.

In 02 snippet You are deleting topic and then redirecting to deleted topic and Trying to get it With Which Of Course Will Return `404 not found` Code

Solution:

```
public function destroy( Topic $topic)
{
    if ($topic != null) {
       $group_id = $topic->group_id;

       $topic->delete();
       return redirect()->route('topic.index',['id' => $group_id ]) ;     //*******
    }
}
```